# Incorrect favorites count on Twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

So I have created an small java program with Twitter4J. The main purpose is to destroy all of my favorites. However, Twitter seems to be misrepresenting the favs count. This is what I see on my profile:

[image]

I know it's in Spanish but it translates as "You have not marked any Tweet as favorite yet". However, on the stats we can see that I have 6,021 favs.

Does anyone know why is this or if someone has noticed before? Calls to the twitter API also return with zero favs.

Thanks!

Comment: I have 1 favorited tweet, but Twitter counts 13.

Answer (score 0):

I had noticed that, but on Tweets.
Sometimes Twitter counts wrong the numbers of Tweets (or in your case favorites) and that happens because those tweets are too old. Maybe you have an  old account (2010-2011) and you had marked those tweets as favorites before.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't see the tweets, but you've still got them favorited. There are several ways this can happen. For example:

- You have been blocked by the profile you favorited
- Their profile is now locked so you can no longer see their tweets you favorited

In both cases, you can't see the tweets themselves, but the tweets aren't deleted, so they still count towards your total.